# Posterior distribution for Weibull scale parameter with censored data

Tags: bayesian, survival, weibull-distribution, conjugate-prior, inverse-gamma-distribution

I am modeling a survival problem using a Weibull distribution with known shape parameter $k$ and unknown scale parameter $\theta$. The PDF and CDF are given by,

\begin{align}
f(t|k,\theta)=\frac{k}{\theta}t^{k-1}e^{-t^k/\theta} \\
F(t|k,\theta)=1 - e^{-t^k/\theta}
\end{align}

I am using an Inverse Gamma prior for $\theta$ (the conjugate prior):

\begin{align}
f(\theta)=\frac{\beta^a}{\Gamma(a)}(\frac{1}{\theta})^{a+1}e^{-\beta/\theta}
\end{align}

Now, I've found some resources showing the derivation of posterior distribution given $n$ data points with event times $x_i$. But here's the thing: in this particular case I only have censored data - I only know how many observed events/deaths $d$ there are for a sample of size $n$ at a given time $t$. So the data are both left- and right-censored.

**Editing for further clarity**: Let $T_i$ represent the actual event time of subject $i$. In my data I have $n$ total observations, $d$ of which have experienced the event before $t$ ($T_i$ < $t$) and $n-d$ of which have not yet ($T_i$ > $t$).

The likelihood function in this case is then:

\begin{align}
p(d,n,t | \theta,k)=(e^{-t^k/\theta})^{n-d}(1-e^{-t^k/\theta})^{d}
\end{align}

And thus the posterior is,

\begin{align}
p(\theta | d,n,t,k)=\frac{(e^{-t^k/\theta})^{n-d}(1-e^{-t^k/\theta})^{d} \frac{\beta^a}{\Gamma(a)}(\frac{1}{\theta})^{a+1}e^{-\beta/\theta}}{\int_0^\infty (e^{-t^k/\theta})^{n-d}(1-e^{-t^k/\theta})^{d} \frac{\beta^a}{\Gamma(a)}(\frac{1}{\theta})^{a+1}e^{-\beta/\theta}d\theta}
\end{align}

I am struggling to get further due to the $(1-e^{-t^k/\theta})^{d}$ term. Any tips?

Comment: Do you know how many observations are left censored and right censored specifically, or do you only know the total number of censored observations?

Comment: Yes - I know that at time $t$ there are $n$ total observations, $d$ of which are left-censored (i.e. $T$ < $t$) and $n-d$ are right-censored (i.e. $T$ > $t$). Edited to be more clear.

Comment: Frankly, I would convert this problem to one of finding the posterior distribution of $p$, the probability that an observation is left-censored (or right-censored, your preference), then apply a change of variable to the resulting distribution to get the posterior for $\theta$.  This would mean abandoning the IG prior on $\theta$ and instead finding one on $p$, preferably the conjugate Beta distribution, but unless your prior is quite informative, that may not be an issue.

Comment: Is that because doing it with the IG prior is not analytically possible with this form of the likelihood function? Is it no longer a conjugate prior?

Comment: Yes, basically.   Of course, others may see a way through that integral where I cannot.   The binomial likelihood approach with conjugate prior I tentatively suggest gives you a Beta posterior, and the change of variable shouldn't be too painful to work through.